# set custom primary key in Rails not id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Rails - I want to set another primary key say :r_id, instead of :**id**.

Also r_id a number should not increment automatically, I want to set it manually on the basis of values that i have in my constant.

What all steps need to be taken, as Table ROLE is already in DB and i want to change it using **change_table** not **create_table**. so that I can refer my Role table record like **User.last.role** which should pick **r_id** NOT **id** in my Role table.

Comment: maybe this will give you an answer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

> Also r_id a number should not increment automatically, I want to set it manually on the basis of values that i have in my constant.

Why would you want that? I'm really curious, since it's very unconventional way to approach DB design and primary keys in particular. I can't think of valid use case for that.

Comment: because I can not associate user with Role.id, as there may be change or deletion, and also if you truncate not delete the whole Role table the number start from the next value not from 1, in that case my app will crash.

Comment: I really think you should read about relations and foreign keys some more. If  user can have only only role you just add role_id column to your users table, that is it. If user can have many roles you can user so called "cross-table": id, user_id, role_id. First option is much better in terms of simplicity though. Also you should add foreign key constraint to your users table to prohibit deleting any role that yet has users attached to it. Rails 4.2 support foreign keys, for Rails 3 there is a [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) gem.